# How to repeat a command n times then exit?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I want to automate an installation and I need to run the downloaded installer with gksu. I have tried:

```
attempt=0
  until
  gksu command; do
    attempt=$((attempt + 1))
    if [ "$attempt" -gt 3 ]; then
      exit 1
    fi
  done
```

but it doesn't exit until it reaches the third attempt. It doesn't matter if gksu has exited with exit code 0 or with a non zero exit code. What I would like to be happen is:
`while gksu command's exit code is not 0 and attempt number is not 3 repeat gksu command.
If exit code is not 0 but attempt number is 3, exit the whole script.
If exit code is 0 leave cycle and continue processing the script.`
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `seq` available, you could do:

```
for attempt in $(seq 1 3)
do
  gksu command && break
done
```

If `seq` is not available, but you have (and want to use) bash:

```
for((attempt=1;attempt<=3;attempt++))
do 
  gksu command && break
done
```

or even simpler (hat tip to [drewbenn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4443/drewbenn)):

```
for attempt in {1..3} 
do
  gksu command && break
done
```

Comment: for((attempt=1;attempt<=3;attempt++))
do
  gksu xampp-linux-x64-5.6.21-0-installer.run && break
done 51: ../xampp-install.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: @drewbenn thanks! I'm going to trying it out after the script has downloaded the installer file.

Comment: @user275214 does xampp-install.sh specify something other than bash (or ksh or zsh) ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I only created this script because i wanted to learn something other than PHP SQL or C# (these are what they teach in school). I didn't even think about publishing it, not to mention about rewriting it to other shells.